# Model.create with hasTrigger true return typeError attribute.type.toSql is not a function

Tags: sql-server, node.js, sequelize.js, tedious

When I set hasTrigger true in Model.create, I have this TypeError :

> attribute.type.toSql is not a function at Object.insertQuery
>   (/Users/momo/www/api.test.com/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract
>   query-generator.js:128:90)

Could someone please help me?

Comment: add your model code here

Comment: Any resolution here? I am getting a similar error with the `hasTrigger` set to true

Comment: on my side no resolution